# Wix: setting the version of the installer

Tags: wix, installation, windows-installer, wix3.5, wix3

I am currently trying to set the version of the installer that I create using Wix toolkit like in the below code:

```
<Product Id="*" UpgradeCode="..." Name="App Name" 
         Version="!(bind.FileVersion.MyApplicationVersion)"

<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
 <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
  <Directory Id="INSTALLDIR" Name="CompanyName">
   <Directory Id="SUBDIR" Name="Application Name">
     <Component Id="ApplicationFiles" Guid="*">
        <File Id="MyApplicationVersion" Name="app.exe" Id="ApplicationFile1" 
              Source="app.exe" Vital="yes" />
     </Component>
    </Directory>
   </Directory>
  </Directory>
```

This builds ok but I see that the version number is not updated in the Add/Remove panel. I have read that the one that I see in this panel is display version and what I is nothing to do with the display version. My question is, what is the purpose of having two different versions (display version and product version)?

And of course, how can verify that I set the product version correctly? I have checked the debug logs but it's nowhere. I am wondering if my above bode works ok or not.

The third question is, of course, how can I set the display version? I know that it can be changed in registry but I am looking for a way to change it in wxs file.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That scenario works for me, as long as the .exe file has a legal product version (<255.255.65535.65535).

What do you mean by "updated"? Is this a clean install or an upgrade? What's the version in app.exe? What, if anything, shows up in the ARP `Version` column? What shows up in the Uninstall key in the registry?

Comment: I tried both clean and upgrade. In both cases, it shows 1.1.0 which is the version that I manually filled in Version before I had the above code. Somehow it is not cleaned, or the above code doesn't update it. App.exe version is 1.3.0.463. How can I see ARP Version and Uninstall key? I checked HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall but no matching name with my UpgradeCode.

Comment: If your package is 32-bit, it'll be in Wow6432Node. Also, you can use the Orca tool to open the .msi, look in the Property table, and see what the ProductVersion property is set to.

Comment: It says ProductVersion 1.1.0. So, does it mean that the above code didn't do anything? Am I missing something?

Comment: Couldn't say without a real project. The code in your question has an error (two Id attributes). Is it possible the id in !(bind) doesn't match?

Comment: and the discussion stops here :)

Comment: It should be pointed out that Windows Installer documents the [product version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370859(v=vs.85).aspx) as three fields. The fourth field is legal and is stored and displayed but when Windows Installer compares versions it only compares the first three fields. Personally, I haven't found a scenario where the fourth field gives me any value.